# c++: strange double multiplication error

Tags: c++, double

I use VC++ 2010 compiler. My below code gives 509:

```
double volume = 5.1;
int n = static_cast<unsigned int>(volume * 100.0);
```

Do i miss something?

Thanks

Comment: yes u miss something... static_cast<int>(..)

Comment: This is soooooo duplicated here. Look up IEEE754 and floating point issues here on [SO]. Basically, 5.1 can not be exactly represented, and in fact it is actually taken into count as `5.099999999<something>`

Comment: I think that your code does not compile. I suggest using `round`

Comment: @Mario 'int' also gives the same result.

Comment: @xyzt in your 1st post you didn't write the `<..>` after the `static_cast`. This is what I was writing about.

Comment: The cast is irrelevant and redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point data types cannot represent all numbers. Since your computer uses binary floating point, the only representable numbers are of the form *s2<sup>e</sup>* where *s* is the significand, and *e* is the exponent. And it is easy enough to see that 5.1 does not fit that mould. It is not exactly representable.

This [page](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=5.1) shows you the closest exactly representable double precision binary floating point value to 5.1. The value is:

```
5.09999 99999 99999 64472 86321 19949 90706 44378 66210 9375
```

So the closest value to 5.1 is slightly less than 5.1. Multiply it by 100 and truncate, and you have 509.

The standard reference from which to learn more about the topic is David Goldberg's [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0):

5.1 represented as 5.099999, it will be 509.9990 when you multiply with 100.0 .It will 509 after converting to int.